# Disappear value 0 on output form

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have an ad's website. There need to enter add description some more and telephone number. The telephone number starts 0, like 07780046 but after saving add appears without 0 is like 7780046. 
Any idea what's wrong?

Script for filling form:

```
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><b>Telefono nr.</b></td>
            <td><input name="telephone" type="telephone" id="telephone" size="30" maxlength="13" value=""></td>
        </tr>
```

and script output. Add page:

```
    <?php if($ad['telephone']){ ?>
<b><?php echo "Telephone n."; ?></b>: 
<?php echo $ad['telephone']; ?>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the column type of the phone number column in your database? Have you set it to `int`?

Comment: As a note: I think `tel` is the right input type and you could add a pattern like: `pattern="[0-9]{13}"`.

Comment: Hi. Was set to bigint. Is not working with any int ether. Sets to defult value. All posted ads had same telephone number.

Comment: pattern="[0-9]{13}" is not working ether, but i like it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the telephone number as a string. I doubt you will want to do any math operations on it.

If you want to validate your phone numbers check out the answer below:

[A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: It's working! Database set to String "chart".  No Math :)))
Thank you Dewi.